# (How to/Can I) show irrational numbers?

Tags: irrational-numbers

This might sounds stupid, but I really don't know can I show **Irrational numbers** in proves? And if so, how to show it?

For example, when I want to show **Rational numbers**, I do this:

## $\frac{m}{n}
$ , $m, n $ *are integer* $,$ $n\ne0$

Can I do something like that with **Irrational numbers**?

Comment: That depends on the number you want to prove the irrationality of... Say, $\sqrt{n}$ where $n$ is not a perfect square is easily proven to be irrational whereas $e$ and $\pi$ have more complicated proofs.

Comment: @M.B. - I think the OP wants some kind of a "closed form", not how to prove a number is irrational

Comment: There's no way of describing irrationals that's as simple as the way you've described a rational. It's easy enough, though, to simply say that a number is not rational. This, as you likely know, is a common way to show that a number is irrational: assume it were (i.e., equal to $n/m$ for $n, m$ integers) and then argue to a contradiction. This is seen in many proofs that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Comment: One can easily construct numbers that are irrational if and only if the Goldbach conjecture is true, for example. Thus an (ir)rationality proof can be arbitrarily complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A real number $a$ is irrational iff its decimal (or binary) expansion doesn't become ultimately periodic. You can formulate this in the following way: $$a=a_0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots\qquad\bigl(a_0\in{\mathbb Z}, \ a_k\in\{0,1,\ldots,9\}\ (k\geq1)\bigr)$$
is irrational iff $\forall p\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq1}$, $\forall n\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq1}$ there is a $k>n$ with $a_k\ne a_{k+p}$.

Comment: Your definition is right. But I couldn't undrestand how can we sure that the number won't become repeating?

Comment: @MostafaFarz'an: That's exactly what is assured by the condition "$\ \forall p\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq1}$, $\forall n\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq1}$ there is a $k>n$ with $a_k\ne a_{k+p}\ $". Think about it!

Answer (score 1):

You can say it is an element of $\mathbb{R}$ that is not in $\mathbb{Q}$.

There is no "general representation" of irrational numbers

Answer (score 1):

In principle, as you point out, showing that a number $r$ is rational is easy. All we need to do is to **exhibit** integers $a$ and $b$, with $b\ne 0$, such that $a=rb$.

Proving that a number $x$ is *irrational* is in principle, and often in practice, much harder. We have to show that there do not exist integers $a$ and $b$, with $b\ne 0$, such that $a=xb$. So in principle we have to examine all ordered pairs $(a,b)$ of integers, with $b\ne 0$, and show that none of them can possibly "work."

This in principle involves examining an infinite set. That cannot be done by simply exhibiting a pair of integers, like in a proof of rationality. Sometimes, as in the case $x=\sqrt{2}$, there is a relatively simple proof of irrationality. But all too often, like in the case of the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma$, no proof of irrationality is known, despite the fact that considerable effort has been expended trying to prove that $\gamma$ is irrational.