# How can define irrational numbers in general

Tags: real-analysis

We know all the irrational numbers cannot be written as the ratio of two rational numbers like all the square roots of not perfect squares 2,3,5,... Not all real numbers are equal to a square number. In general, every number not equal number the power $n$ for all $n$ in rational numbers. In addition Euler number $e$ and $\pi$ and the golden ratio is $φ$ always if want to to prove any result we used these numbers as examples. Are there other irrational  numbers that are not  mentioned?

Comment: Yes, uncountably many.  The first sentence says it all.  A real number other than the quotient of two integers is irrational.  It's hopeless to try to list them.

Comment: Most numbers are irrational, this can be put in rigorous terms using measure theory.  Think of this as saying, if you randomly select a real number you will pick an irrational number with probability equal to 1

Comment: It can be proven that the number is irrational if and only if its decimal expansion is not finite and does not "repeat" (as a finite cycle) after some point. Thus, if you can imagine a number such as $0.12345\ldots$ and make sure the digits never repeat, you've found a way to generate irrational numbers. (Also, this is the way you can generate all the *rational* numbers: just make the decimal expansion finite, or infinite where digits repeat after some point, e.g. $3.14159292929292\ldots$.)

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443877/how-to-prove-that-x-0-1234567891011-dots-is-irrational

Comment: There are uncountably many numbers with even a stronger property , so-called transcendental numbers. They are not even the root of a polynomial with integer coefficients. Examples include $\pi$ , $e$ and the solutions (also the complex solutions) of $x=\cos(x)$ The algebraic numbers (numbers that are a root of a polynomial with integer coefficients) are not only countable, they form a field (which is even algebraically closed)

Comment: You are also advised to make a difference between: (a) The *definition* of irrational numbers: "A number $x$ is irrational if it is not equal to any fraction $p/q$ with $p, q$-integers ", and (b) The *examples* of irrational numbers (such as $\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{5}, \varphi, e, \pi$ etc.). The statement (a) fully characterizes the irrational numbers. The examples (b) can *never* exhaust that definition - there are just too many irrational numbers!

Comment: @StinkingBishop Very good point ! In fact, "almost all" irrational numbers are even uncomputable !

Comment: "*Are there other irrational numbers that are not mentioned?*"  As alluded to already, there are uncountably infinitely many more.  That said, proving that a particular number is irrational can be particularly challenging.  It is obvious that $q+x$ where $q$ is rational and $x$ is irrational will always be irrational (*so things like $3+\pi$ will still be irrational*) but it is not so obvious when talking about $x+y$ where $x$ and $y$ are both irrational.  There are examples in both directions and many unknowns.  We don't even have a proof yet for if $\pi+e$ is irrational

Comment: Since i can write any number randomly by infiniting and repeating decimal expansion to get an irrational number so i can not say all  irrational number must be limit of sequences of rational numbers, like when i can that all rational number must be limitd of sequence of irrational numbers. What u think?

Comment: @Bsmah this is exactly right. Every irrational number is a limit of a sequence of rational numbers. What you say is also my preferred way of showing that. Indeed, for example, $\pi$ is the limit of the sequence of rational numbers: $3, 3.1, 3.14, 3.141, 3.1415, 3.14159,\ldots$. However, the digits of $\pi$ don't start repeating at any point, as $\pi$ itself is irrational.

Comment: @Bsmah this is exactly right. Every irrational number is a limit of a sequence of rational numbers. What you say is also my preferred way of showing that. Indeed, for example, π is the limit of the sequence of rational numbers: 3,3.1,3.14,3.141,3.1415,3.14159,…. However, the digits of π don't start repeating at any point, as π itself is irrational. – Stinking Bishop 4 mins ago

Comment: When it comes to (non-)rationality, rather than thinking in terms of decimal expansion, I like to consider continued fractions instead. If the continued fraction representation is finite, it represents a rational, if it's infinite, it represents an irrational. Take some infinite sequence of naturals, anything, repeating or not, combine it with some $a_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$, you get the continued fraction representation of an irrational.

Comment: Yah you  pick especially pi as example to prove there is sequence of rational convergent to pi. That is right but there are infinitn incontable  irrational number. My question is all irrational number in real numbers is limited of sequence of rational numbers

Comment: Yes, *every* real number, irrational or otherwise, can be seen as the limit of a sequence of rational numbers.  Following from the earlier example, given a number $x$ (*for example $\pi$ but doesn't need to be $\pi$*) you have $x=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\lfloor 10^n\cdot x\rfloor \cdot 10^{-n}$.  There are of course other ways you can express numbers too, you can have an irrational be the limit of a sequence of irrationals, or a rational the limit of a sequence of irrationals, etc... these aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Bsmah You understand that, whatever I did for $\pi$, I can do for any real number!

Answer (score 3):

The [Liouville numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number)

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{2^{k!}}$$ where $\{a_k\}$ is any non-eventually vanishing binary sequence, already provides you with an uncountable number of irrational numbers.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for noticing the typo. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks  evey who answered me that really help me